# Map update periodically in forestadmin using leaflet

Tags: javascript, ember.js, leaflet, maps, forestadmin

I am using map to show riders while driving. Map is showing location as a marker on Map.
But my map is not updating after data updated in `mongodb`. I am using **forestadmin** and node js. In **forestadmin**, I am using smartview where I will have to use *ember.js*. I am showing `leaflet OpenStreetMap` map.

here is the javascript I am using:

```
export default Component.extend(SmartViewMixin, {
  store: service(),

  tagName: "",

  map: null,
  loaded: false,

  init(...args) {
    this._super(...args);

    this.loadPlugin();
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    this.displayMap();
  },

  onRecordsChange: observer("records", function () {
    this.displayMap();
  }),

  loadPlugin() {
    scheduleOnce("afterRender", this, () => {
      $.getScript(
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js",
        () => {
          $.getScript(
            "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.js",
            () => {
              this.set("loaded", true);
              this.displayMap();
            }
          );
        }
      );

      const headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      const cssLeafletLink = document.createElement("link");
      cssLeafletLink.type = "text/css";
      cssLeafletLink.rel = "stylesheet";
      cssLeafletLink.href =
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css";

      headElement.appendChild(cssLeafletLink);

      const cssDrawLink = document.createElement("link");
      cssDrawLink.type = "text/css";
      cssDrawLink.rel = "stylesheet";
      cssDrawLink.href =
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.css";

      headElement.appendChild(cssDrawLink);
    });
  },

  displayMap() {
    if (!this.loaded) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.map) {
      this.map.off();
      this.map.remove();
      this.map = null;
    }

    const markers_arr = [];

    this.records.forEach(function (record) {
      markers_arr.push([
        record.get("forest-latitude"),
        record.get("forest-longitude"),
        record.get("id"),
        record.get("forest-userId.forest-email"),
       
        record.get("forest-userId.forest-bikeModel"),
        record.get("forest-userId.forest-bikeRegNo"),
        record.get("forest-userId.forest-phone"),
      ]);
    });
    var map = L.map("map").setView(
      new L.LatLng(markers_arr[0][0], markers_arr[0][1]),
      7
    );

    const osmUrl =
      "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    const osmAttrib =
      '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>';
    const osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, { attribution: osmAttrib });
    map.addLayer(osm);

    var markers = [];

    markers_arr.forEach(function (mark) {
      var foo = "ID: "+mark[2] + "\n <br>Email: " + mark[3]+ "\n <br>Phone: " + mark[6]+ "\n <br>Bike Model: " + mark[4] + "\n <br>Bike #: " + mark[5]
      var marker1 = L.marker([mark[0], mark[1]] )
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup(foo);
      markers.push(marker1);

      marker1.on("mouseover", function (ev) {
        marker1.openPopup();
      });
    });

    function markerFunction(id) {
      for (var i in markers) {
        var markerID = markers[i].options.title;
        if (markerID == id) {
          markers[i].openPopup();
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<style>
  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
  }  
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
```

I also use `fetchRecord` in HTML but it not updating latest data.

```
<button {{action 'fetchRecords'}}>
  Refresh data
</button>
```

Help me

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have nothing that recalculate your map when your records change.
First what I would do in your case if you want it to update automatically is to retrieve the records every second or something like that so you could do something like below but I'm not sure it will fix your issue.

What I find weird is that you are destroying your map every time you fetch your data. Can't you just refresh the mark ?
This might be your issue.

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { later } from '@ember/runloop';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import {
  triggerSmartAction, deleteRecords, getCollectionId, loadExternalStyle, loadExternalJavascript,
} from 'client/utils/smart-view-utils';

export default class extends Component {
  @service store;

  @tracked map = null;
  @tracked loaded = false;

  @action
  async loadPlugin() {
    loadExternalStyle('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css');
    loadExternalStyle('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.css');

    await loadExternalJavascript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js')
    await loadExternalJavascript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.js')

    this.loaded = true;
    this.displayMap();
  }

  displayMap() {
    if (!this.loaded) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.map) {
      this.map.remove();
      this.map = null;
    }

    const markers_arr = this.args.records.map((record) => [
      record.get("forest-latitude"),
      record.get("forest-longitude"),
      record.get("id"),
      record.get("forest-userId.forest-email"),
      record.get("forest-userId.forest-bikeModel"),
      record.get("forest-userId.forest-bikeRegNo"),
      record.get("forest-userId.forest-phone"),
    ]);

    const map = L.map("map").setView(
      new L.LatLng(markers_arr[0][0], markers_arr[0][1]),
      7
    );

    const osmUrl =
      "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    const osmAttrib =
      '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>';
    const osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, { attribution: osmAttrib });
    map.addLayer(osm);

    const markers = [];

    markers_arr.forEach(function (mark) {
      const foo = "ID: "+mark[2] + "\n <br>Email: " + mark[3]+ "\n <br>Phone: " + mark[6]+ "\n <br>Bike Model: " + mark[4] + "\n <br>Bike #: " + mark[5]
      const marker1 = L.marker([mark[0], mark[1]] )
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup(foo);
      markers.push(marker1);

      marker1.on("mouseover", function (ev) {
        marker1.openPopup();
      });
    });

    // This is what will refresh the records every 5s
    later(() => {
      this.refreshRecords();
    }, 5000)
  }

  @action
  async refreshRecords() {
    await this.args.fetchRecords();
    this.displayMap();
  }
}
```

```
<style>
  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
  }  
</style>
<div id="map" {{did-insert this.loadPlugin}}></div>
```